# What would be the proper way to get an instance of realm (kotlin sdk, version 0.10.0)? Alternative to Realm.getDefaultInstance() on Java SDK?

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I initialized realm in my Application classe like this:

```
val realmConfig = RealmConfiguration.Builder(schema =
    setOf(User::class)
    )       .name("myrealm_DB.db")
            .schemaVersion(1)
            .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
            .log(LogLevel.ALL)
            .build()

    realm = Realm.open(configuration = realmConfig)
```

What would be the proper way to get an instance of realm in another activity? Since in the kotlin sdk we dont have **Realm.getDefaultInstance()** method? Is there a way to create like a global RealmManager class?

Answer (score 0):

Since it's very specific to each pattern, and model that you used while developing application and enterprise models there is not a basic answer, unfortunately. Still, I'll share one pattern I used to do while working with Realm.

```
object RealmProcessor {
  private var realmInstance: Realm? = nil
  fun startRealm(someSpecialProperties: <Type>, completion: () -> Unit? = {}){
    runInSafeQueue ({
      try {
        val config = RealmConfiguration.Builder(
          setOf(
            User::class,
            Message::class,
            MessageEmbed::class,
            MessageViewer::class,
            MessageRecipient::class,
            Inbox::class,
            InboxUser::class,
            Sync::class
          )
        )

        config.schemaVersion(1)
        config.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()

        // We're using also Realm-JS, since we want the same directory that the JS thread created.
        config.name("my-percious-realm-$my_custom_property.realm")

        realmInstance = Realm.open(config.build())
      } catch(e: Error) {
        logError("Realm start error", thrown = e)
      }
    })
  }

  // Since the threads has to be same for write operations which we used for opening Realm making it singleton with one dispatcher.
  private fun runInSafeQueue(runner: suspend () -> Unit?, didCatch: (Error) -> Unit = { _ -> }) {
    GlobalScope.launch {
      try {
        runner()
      } catch (e: Error) {
        didCatch(e)
      }
    }
  }

  // This is very basic example with making this Object class a generic Realm accessor so you initialize it in very first activity that your app used you can easily keep accessing it from any activity
  inline fun <reified T: BaseRealmObject>getFromRealm(id: Int): RealmResults<T>? {
    return realmInstance?.query(T::class, "id == $0", id)?.find()
  }

  fun <T: RealmObject>createInRealm(objectToCopyRealm: T) {
    runInSafeQueue({
      realmInstance?.write {
        copyToRealm(objectToCopyRealm)
        null
      }
    })
  }

  fun changeUserValue(changedValue: Int) {
    runInSafeQueue({
      realmInstance?.write {
        val objectToChange = getFromRealm<User>(20)
        objectToChange?.first()?.personalMessageRoom = changedValue
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Hope helps anyone they looking for some point for the start

Answer (score 0):

You can create a singleton to save the configuration and get the realm instance.

```
class RealmDB {
    companion object {
        private var instance: Realm? = null

        fun getInstance(): Realm {
            if (instance == null || instance!!.isClosed()) {
                val config = RealmConfiguration.create(schema = setOf(MyRealmObject::class))
                instance = Realm.open(config)
            }
            return instance!!
        }
    }
}
```

and use like:

```
      val realm = RealmDB.getInstance()

        realm.writeBlocking {
            copyToRealm(MyRealmObject().apply {
                ....
            })
        }
```